# StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, multithreading, streaming, object

My problem is when it tries to read the object the second time, it throws the exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1356)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at Client.run(BaseStaInstance.java:313)

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1356)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at Client.run(BaseStaInstance.java:313)
```

The first time I send the exact same object message; however, when I try doing the same thing the second time, it throws the error above. Do I need to re-intialize the readObject() method? I even printed out the message object that is being received by the line below and its exact the same as the first instance where it works ok.

```
Object buf = myInput.readObject();
```

I'm assuming there's some problem with appending, but I really have no use for appending. I just want to read a fresh line everytime.
I'd really appreciate some help in fixing this bug. Thank you.

==================================

Before that one line, I'm just creating the input and output objects for the socket in the run() method. The object declaration is outside the run() method in the class:-

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        sleep((int) 1 * 8000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        //Creating input and output streams to transfer messages to the server
        myOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
        myInput = new ObjectInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            buf = myInput.readObject();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You're right; I don't close the object. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure where to close the object

Comment: NB You should catch EOFException and not treat it as an error: don't log or print the stack trace; just let it terminate the reading loop. I don't know why you're catching UnknownHostException where you are: it can't be thrown from within the corresponding try block. The sleep() is just literally a waste of time. Remove it.

Answer (score 98):

The underlying problem is that you are using a new `ObjectOutputStream` to write to a stream that you have already used a prior `ObjectOutputStream` to write to. These streams have headers which are written and read by the respective constructors, so if you create another `ObjectOutputStream` you will write a new header, which starts with - guess what? - `0xAC,` and the existing `ObjectInputStream` isn't expecting another header at this point so it barfs.

In the Java Forums thread cited by @trashgod, I should have left out the part about 'anew for each object at both ends': that's just wasteful. Use a single OOS and OIS for the life of the socket, and don't use any other streams on the socket.

If you want to forget what you've written, use `ObjectOutputStream.reset().`

And don't use any other streams or `Readers` or `Writers` on the same socket. The object stream APIs can handle all Java primitive datatypes and all `Serializable` classes.

Comment: +1 @rookie: This is the correct answer, and from the original source! :-)

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar I don't know what you're asking me that isn't already answered above.

Comment: @AndroidOptimist What code? I haven't posted any code. The essence of this answer is to *remove* code.