# ObjectInputStream exception

Tags: java, java-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac)

Hello guys I am trying to read object from the stream over the network... I am using ReadInputObject method ... and I am implementing it inside a thread to recieve the data ... here is the while loop in the thread

```
while((dp = (DataPackage) ois.readObject()) != null)
        {

             Ball b = new Ball();
             b.setX(dp.x);
             b.setY(dp.y);
             jTextField1.setText(b.getX() + "    " +b.getY());
             b.paint(ob.getGraphics());
             b.setVisible(true);
             ois.reset();

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 1 is Here");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 2 is here");
    }
```

the problem is that the ois gets the first object and then .... it goes inside the exception and prints out this 
Error 1 is here

here is the code where I send the object

```
DataPackage dp = new DataPackage();
    dp.x=b1.getX();
    dp.y=b1.getY();
    dp.t=b1.getT();
    dp.dx=(int)b1.getDx();
    dp.dy=(int)b1.getDy();

    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Server_login.client.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game_Painters_right.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        oos.writeObject(dp);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game_Painters_right.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

what is the wrong in my code ??
thank you

Comment: Print the StackTrace and add it to your question. Use `ex.printStackTrace()` in your `catch`-blocks.

Comment: java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
 at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:347)
 at netbeans_gui_swing.Game_Painters_left$5.run(Game_Painters_left.java:221)

Comment: Put the **full** StackTrace into your question...

Comment: This is the full stack dude ..... after I deleted ois.reset();

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
 at netbeans_gui_swing.Client_login$2.run(Client_login.java:98)

Comment: Checking for null is pointless unless you are planning to write a null to the stream. It doesn't return null at the end of the stream: it throws EOFException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, remove the call to `ois.reset()`. Why is it there in the first place?

Comment: Before I didn't use ois.reset() but I wanted to clean the stream and get a new data in it .. that's why I used .reset()... Anyways I deleted it for u and here is the stack trace



java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
 at netbeans_gui_swing.Game_Painters_left$5.run(Game_Painters_left.java:212)

Comment: Then show us the code which sends the DataPackage instances to an ObjectOutputStream at the other side. reset() doesn't do what you think it does. Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29

Comment: I edited the code ... check it out .. included the part where I send the object

Comment: You're trying to read several objects at client side, but you only send one at server-side. You must read exactly the number of objects that have been sent. Trying to read more will lead to an IOException.

Comment: Yes I know ... but the readObject should block whenever there is no input to read ..... !!!

Comment: What does the server do after the object is written in the output stream?

Comment: nothing it just updates the position of the ball again when I click to the button update and send the new positions as an object again

Comment: So, in fact, it sends multiple DataPackage instance, but each time it sends one, it creates a new ObjectOutputStream, right? If so, don't do that? Use the same ObjectOutputStream to send all your objects, just as you're using the same ObjectInputStream to read them all.

Comment: I did it but I still get he same exact problem . 
I initialised the oos in other place and every time I use it to send the datapackage ... but still not working .. the exact same stack trace ...

Comment: dude it is working .. yes u were correct