# StackOverflowError while saving and loading my object in android

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization, stack-overflow

I'm writing an android program and i just ran into a problem.

My program serves to create graphs, run some specific algorithms on them (Dijsktra, BelmanFord, etc.), save the graphs to SD Card and loading them back.

The problem: **If i save a little bigger, more complex graph i get a stackoverflow error..**

Serialization:

```
public void createExternalStoragePublicGraph(String filename) {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("grapher");

    try {
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, filename);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(graphDrawerView.getGraph());
        objectOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error Writing" + filename, e);
    }

}
```

Deserialization:

```
public Graph loadExternalStoragePublicGraph(String filename) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("grapher"), filename);
    Graph graph = null;

    try {

        FileInputStream fint = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fint);
        graph = (Graph) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Deserialization error:", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Graph class:

```
package com.cslqaai.grapher;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Graph implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private boolean directed = false;
    private boolean weighted = false;
    private LinkedList<Vertex> vertexes = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    private LinkedList<Edge> edges = new LinkedList<Edge>();

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Graph(boolean weighted, boolean directed) {
        this.directed = directed;
        this.weighted = weighted;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void add(AbstractGraphObject ago) {
        if (ago instanceof Vertex) {
            this.vertexes.add((Vertex) ago);
        } else if (ago instanceof Edge) {

            this.edges.add((Edge) ago);
        } else {
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean isWeighted() {
        return this.weighted;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean isDirected() {
        return this.directed;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
    public LinkedList<Edge> getEdges() {
        return this.edges;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkedList<Vertex> getVertexes() {
        return this.vertexes;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void reset() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.edges.size(); i++) {
            this.edges.get(i).setColorToDefault();
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void remove(AbstractGraphObject ago) {
        if (ago instanceof Vertex) {
            Log.d("Graph", "Remove Vertex from graph");
            this.vertexes.remove((Vertex) ago);
        } else if (ago instanceof Edge) {
            Log.d("Graph", "Remove Edge to graph");
            this.edges.remove((Edge) ago);
        }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setWeighted(boolean weighted) {
        this.weighted = weighted;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setDirected(boolean directed) {
        this.directed = directed;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Vertex class:

```
package com.cslqaai.grapher;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Vertex extends AbstractGraphObject {

public static final int RADIUS_SIZE = 20;
public static final int SURROUNDING_RADIUS_SIZE = 30;
private static Layer defaultVertexLayer = AbstractGraphObject.defaultLayer;
private static int no = 0;
private static Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint paintColored = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint textBgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final int id;
private String name = null;
private Coord coord;
private Coord cachedCoord;
private ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
private boolean colored = false;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static {
    Vertex.paint.setColor(0xFF0FF5F5);
    Vertex.paintColored.setColor(Color.RED);
    Vertex.textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Vertex.textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Vertex.textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    Vertex.textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    Vertex.textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD));
    Vertex.textBgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Vertex.textBgPaint.setColor(0xFF0FF5F5);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Vertex(Coord coord) {
    super(Vertex.defaultVertexLayer);
    this.id = Vertex.no++;
    this.coord = coord;
    this.recalculate();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Vertex(int x, int y) {
    this(new Coord(x, y));
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void recalculate() {
    this.cachedCoord = new Coord(Math.round((Vertex.baseX + this.coord.getX()) * Vertex.scaleFactor), Math.round((Vertex.baseY + this.coord.getY()) * Vertex.scaleFactor));
    this.onScreen = this.cachedCoord.getX() + Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE > 0 && this.cachedCoord.getY() + Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE > 0
            && this.cachedCoord.getX() - Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE < Vertex.screenWidth && this.cachedCoord.getY() - Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE < this.cachedCoord.getY();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Coord getCoord() {
    return this.coord;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Coord getCachedCoord() {
    return this.cachedCoord;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public int getRadiusSize() {
    return Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.recalculate();

    if (!this.onScreen) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(this.cachedCoord.getX(), this.cachedCoord.getY(), Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE * Vertex.scaleFactor, Vertex.paint);
    if (this.name != null) {
        float width = Vertex.textPaint.measureText(this.name) + 10;
        float height = Vertex.textPaint.getTextSize() + 5;
        canvas.drawRect(this.cachedCoord.getX() - width / 2, this.cachedCoord.getY() - height / 2, this.cachedCoord.getX() + width / 2, this.cachedCoord.getY() + height / 2, Vertex.textBgPaint);
        canvas.drawText(this.name, this.cachedCoord.getX(), this.cachedCoord.getY() + height * 0.25f, Vertex.textPaint);
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private boolean searchingCoordOn(float radius, float pX, float pY) {
    return this.onScreen && ((Math.pow(pX - this.cachedCoord.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(pY - this.cachedCoord.getY(), 2)) < (Math.pow(radius * Vertex.scaleFactor, 2)));
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isOnCoord(float pX, float pY) {
    return this.searchingCoordOn(Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE, pX, pY);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isInCoordSurroundings(float pX, float pY) {
    return this.searchingCoordOn(Vertex.SURROUNDING_RADIUS_SIZE, pX, pY);
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void addEdge(Edge edge) {
    if (!this.edges.contains(edge)) {
        this.edges.add(edge);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public ArrayList<Edge> getEdges() {
    return this.edges;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void removeEdge(Edge edge) {
    if (this.edges.contains(edge)) {
        this.edges.remove(edge);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean hasEdge(Edge edge) {
    return this.edges.contains(edge);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void setDefaultLayer(Layer layer) {
    Vertex.defaultVertexLayer = layer;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static Layer getDefaultLayer() {
    return Vertex.defaultVertexLayer;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void remove(Vertex vertex) {
    Iterator<Edge> edges = vertex.getEdges().iterator();
    while (edges.hasNext()) {
        Edge e = edges.next();
        edges.remove();
        Edge.remove(e);
    }

    Vertex.defaultVertexLayer.remove(vertex);
    if (Vertex.graph != null) {
        Vertex.graph.remove(vertex);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean hasName() {
    return this.name != null;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Edge class:

```
package com.cslqaai.grapher;

import android.graphics.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Edge extends AbstractGraphObject {

public static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
public static final float SENSOR_WIDTH = 50f;
public static final float SURROUNDING_SENSOR_WIDTH = 15f;
public static final float TRIANGLE_SIZE = 8f;
private static Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint paintColored = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Paint textBgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private static Layer defaultEdgeLayer = AbstractGraphObject.defaultLayer;
private static int no = 0;
private final int id;
private int weight = 1;
private Coord cachedSourceCoord;
private Coord cachedTargetCoord;
private Vertex sourceVertex;
private Vertex targetVertex;
private Coord weightCoord;
private boolean colored = false;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static {
    Edge.paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    Edge.paint.setStrokeWidth(Edge.STROKE_WIDTH * Edge.scaleFactor);
    Edge.paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    Edge.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    Edge.paintColored.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    Edge.paintColored.setStrokeWidth(Edge.STROKE_WIDTH * Edge.scaleFactor);
    Edge.paintColored.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    Edge.paintColored.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    Edge.textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Edge.textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Edge.textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    Edge.textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    Edge.textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD));
    Edge.textBgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Edge.textBgPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Edge(Vertex sourceVertex, Vertex targetVertex) {
    super(Edge.defaultEdgeLayer);
    this.id = Edge.no++;
    this.sourceVertex = sourceVertex;
    this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
    this.sourceVertex.addEdge(this);
    this.targetVertex.addEdge(this);
    this.recalculate();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void recalculate() {
    this.cachedSourceCoord = new Coord(Math.round((Edge.baseX + this.sourceVertex.getCoord().getX()) * Edge.scaleFactor), Math.round((Edge.baseY + this.sourceVertex.getCoord().getY()) * Edge.scaleFactor));
    this.cachedTargetCoord = new Coord(Math.round((Edge.baseX + this.targetVertex.getCoord().getX()) * Edge.scaleFactor), Math.round((Edge.baseY + this.targetVertex.getCoord().getY()) * Edge.scaleFactor));

    Line line = new Line(this.cachedSourceCoord, this.cachedTargetCoord);
    this.weightCoord = line.getMiddle();

    this.onScreen = Edge.screenBottomLine.hasIntersection(line)
            || Edge.screenLeftLine.hasIntersection(line)
            || Edge.screenRightLine.hasIntersection(line)
            || Edge.screenTopLine.hasIntersection(line)
            || this.cachedSourceCoord.getX() > 0 && this.cachedSourceCoord.getX() < Edge.screenWidth && this.cachedSourceCoord.getY() > 0 && this.cachedSourceCoord.getY() < Edge.screenHeight
            || this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() > 0 && this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() < Edge.screenWidth && this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() > 0 && this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() < Edge.screenHeight;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.recalculate();

    if (!this.onScreen) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawLine(this.cachedSourceCoord.getX(), this.cachedSourceCoord.getY(), this.cachedTargetCoord.getX(), this.cachedTargetCoord.getY(), this.colored ? Edge.paintColored : Edge.paint);

    if (Edge.graph != null && Edge.graph.isDirected()) {
        Line line = new Line(this.cachedSourceCoord, this.cachedTargetCoord);
        Coord v = line.getVector();
        float t = (float) ((Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE + 5) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(v.getY(), 2)));
        Coord t1 = new Coord((int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() - t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() - t * v.getY()));
        if (!line.isOnLine(t1)) {
            t1 = new Coord((int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() + t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() + t * v.getY()));
        }
        t = (float) ((Vertex.RADIUS_SIZE + 5 + Edge.TRIANGLE_SIZE) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(v.getY(), 2)));
        Coord p = new Coord((int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() - t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() - t * v.getY()));
        if (!line.isOnLine(p)) {
            p = new Coord((int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() + t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() + t * v.getY()));
        }
        v = line.getNormalVector().getVector();
        t = (float) ((Edge.TRIANGLE_SIZE) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(v.getY(), 2)));
        Coord t2 = new Coord((int) (p.getX() - t * v.getX()), (int) (p.getY() - t * v.getY()));
        Coord t3 = new Coord((int) (p.getX() + t * v.getX()), (int) (p.getY() + t * v.getY()));
        Path path = new Path();

        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(t1.getX(), t1.getY());
        path.lineTo(t2.getX(), t2.getY());
        path.lineTo(t3.getX(), t3.getY());
        path.lineTo(t1.getX(), t1.getY());
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, Edge.paint);
    }

    if (Edge.graph != null && Edge.graph.isWeighted()) {
        float width = Edge.textPaint.measureText(Integer.toString(this.weight)) + 10;
        float height = Edge.textPaint.getTextSize() + 5;
        canvas.drawRect(this.weightCoord.getX() - width / 2, this.weightCoord.getY() - height / 2, this.weightCoord.getX() + width / 2, this.weightCoord.getY() + height / 2, Edge.textBgPaint);
        canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(this.weight), this.weightCoord.getX(), this.weightCoord.getY() + height * 0.25f, Edge.textPaint);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private boolean searchingCoordOn(float distance, float pX, float pY) {
    Coord p = new Coord((int) pX, (int) pY);
    Coord v = (new Line(this.cachedSourceCoord, this.cachedTargetCoord)).getNormalVector().getVector();
    float t = (float) (distance / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(v.getY(), 2)));
    Coord c1 = new Coord((int) (this.cachedSourceCoord.getX() - t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedSourceCoord.getY() - t * v.getY()));
    Coord c2 = new Coord((int) (this.cachedSourceCoord.getX() + t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedSourceCoord.getY() + t * v.getY()));
    Coord c3 = new Coord((int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getX() - t * v.getX()), (int) (this.cachedTargetCoord.getY() - t * v.getY()));
    Coord v1 = new Coord(c2.getX() - c1.getX(), c2.getY() - c1.getY());
    Coord v2 = new Coord(c3.getX() - c1.getX(), c3.getY() - c1.getY());
    v = Coord.minus(p, c1);

    return this.onScreen
            && 0 <= Coord.dotProduct(v, v1) && Coord.dotProduct(v, v1) <= Coord.dotProduct(v1, v1)
            && 0 <= Coord.dotProduct(v, v2) && Coord.dotProduct(v, v2) <= Coord.dotProduct(v2, v2);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isOnCoord(float pX, float pY) {
    return this.searchingCoordOn(Edge.SENSOR_WIDTH / 2, pX, pY);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isInCoordSurroundings(float pX, float pY) {
    return this.searchingCoordOn(Edge.SURROUNDING_SENSOR_WIDTH / 2, pX, pY);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Vertex getSourceVertex() {
    return this.sourceVertex;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Vertex getTargetVertex() {
    return this.targetVertex;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void setDefaultLayer(Layer layer) {
    Edge.defaultEdgeLayer = layer;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static Layer getDefaultLayer() {
    return Edge.defaultEdgeLayer;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void remove(Edge edge) {
    edge.getSourceVertex().removeEdge(edge);
    edge.getTargetVertex().removeEdge(edge);
    Edge.defaultEdgeLayer.remove(edge);
    if (Edge.graph != null) {
        Edge.graph.remove(edge);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public int getWeight() {
    return this.weight;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setColored() {
    this.colored = true;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setColorToDefault() {
    this.colored = false;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static ArrayList<Edge> getEdgesBetween(Vertex v1, Vertex v2) {
    ArrayList<Edge> edges = v1.getEdges();
    ArrayList<Edge> edgesRet = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    for (Edge edge : edges) {
        if (v2.hasEdge(edge)) {
            edgesRet.add(edge);
        }
    }
    return edges;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

> The reason for this is that the "normal" serialization would for each entry recursively invoke another writeObject(e), and for long lists this would give a StackOverflowError. The iterative serialization avoids this.

I found this on stackoverflow. I think my problem is related to my long LinkedLists..

Any ideas, advices how to properly serialize and deserialize my Graph object?

Thank You In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a fast fix, you could try substuting the LinkedList List implemetnations with ArrayLists. You didn't give enough details (the exact exception and the implementations of the vertexes and edges would be helpful), but what you quoted might be right: we run out of memory because of the recursive calls. I didn't try, but the ArrayList default Java serialization would avoid this issue.

For a really good solution, the serialization methods of the graph objects could be re-implemented, or a tested and more memory efficient library could be used (eg. [kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/)).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778277/objectinputstream-exception) question would also be helpful.

Comment: I replaced my LinkedLists with ArrayLists but it hasn't resolved my issue. I've pasted my Vertex and Edge implementation to my question. Maybe it helps. Afternoon i will try kyro. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try runnning your program with more RAM. StackOverFlowError means, that the stack is filled and cant take any other method. What you could also do, is run the deserialization in another Thread; They have a seperate stack. There are several ways to do so, I recommend using the classes from java.util.concurrent.