# When I write more than one object I get this IO error "invalid type code: AC" why?

Tags: java, serialization

This is my file handling class....i dont have any errors in any other classes ...the program is also overwring the data in the file..it is not appending

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class FileHandling {

    FileHandling() {
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customerObject, String filePath) {

        ObjectOutputStream output;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            output.writeObject(customerObject);
            output.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ioexception) {
            System.err.println("Error with file");
        }
    // end addCustomer function
    }

    public void retrieveCustomerData(String filePath) {

        Customer record = new Customer();

        ObjectInputStream input;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileOut = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            input = new ObjectInputStream(fileOut);

        }

        catch (IOException ioexception) {
            System.err.println("Error with file1");
            return;
        }

        try {
            while (true && input != null) {

                record = (Customer) input.readObject();

                System.out.println(record.getFirstName());
                System.out.println(record.getLastName());
                System.out.println(record.getEmailAddress());

            // end while loop   
            }

        // end try block    
        } catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {

        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException ioexception) {
            System.err.println("Class not Found");
        }

        catch (IOException ioexception) {
            System.err.println("Error with file2");
            System.err.println(ioexception.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Error closing file");
        }
    // end retrieveCustomerData function
    }

// end class fileHandling
}
```

Comment: Doesn't hurt to do a search before posting :3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac

Comment: class Customer was serializable   here is the stack trace  [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4c5e43ee

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you @ChuckFricano

Comment: So the stack trace is --> Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4c5e43ee?  Try again.

Comment: @ChuckFricano oops ..here it is   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
 at FileHandling.retrieveCustomerData(FileHandling.java:59)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:21)

Comment: Your problem lies with trying to append to OOS.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream

Comment: @ChuckFricano TY! ... the professor made a change to our instructions saying we didn't have to append with an OOS anymore. I guess he realized after his email was flooded that he asked us to do something that couldnt be done. tyvm for your time :D

Comment: Answer/Accept your original question yourself in the "Your Answer" area with what you found to be the problem/solution.