# Sending ArrayList from server side to client side using TCP over socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to send an Object from Server Side to Client Side but i can't find the problem. Here is the error I'm getting on the Client side:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 43
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at connection.MainClient.doAll(MainClient.java:56)
at connection.TestScreen$2.actionPerformed(TestScreen.java:82)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here below is the Server Side method:
The seperate method in the Infinite loop is just reading from a file and parsing the Usernames and passwords to ArrayList that are instance variables in the Server class.

```
    public void doStuff() throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    String inputLine;
    out.println("Connected");
    while(true)
    {
        seperate();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("users"))
                objectOutput.writeObject(getUserNames());
            else
                if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("pass"))
                    objectOutput.writeObject(getPassWords());
                else
                    if(inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                        objectOutput.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Here below is the client side requesting the info from the server:

```
public boolean doAll(String name, String pass) throws Exception
{
    try 
    {
        kkSocket = new Socket("PC", 5001);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: PC.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: PC.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(kkSocket.getInputStream());

    out.println("user");
    Object obj = objectInput.readObject();
    users = (ArrayList<String>)obj;
    out.println("pass");
    obj = objectInput.readObject();
    this.pass = (ArrayList<String>)obj;
    out.println("stop");
    objectInput.close();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    kkSocket.close();

    if(userIsRegistered(name,pass))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I am new at learning Server sockets and sockets but what i am trying to accomplish here is this. When I press a button in another class I do this:

```
MainClient b = new MainClient();
login = b.doAll(userField.getText(),passField.getText());
Login is obviously a boolean.
```

Pretty much a login system over server to cleint where when the login button is pressed it invokes a client to connect to this server and get the list of Users and Passes on the server that is stored in a text file in the specified directory. Then when the client recieves this information it checks if it could possibly be a user from the Strings i get form the two text fields and returns true or false. Then closes the socket to the server and it should just keep reconnecting everytime right ?

My main problem is how do you fix the error it keeps throwing ?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac

Comment: @Chuck Norris writes **perfect** code the first time around. Bugs are afraid of his roundhouse kicks, hence why his code has no bugs.

Comment: @Chuck Norris bugs is considered a feature. A feature that is needed for all developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow of your code is as follows:

1. Server started and waiting for connection with client
2. Server accepts a connection from a client using `serverSocket.accept()`.
3. Server sends a `String` message("Connected") to client using `PrintWriter` object via `out.println("Connected")`.
4. **Client is reading that message using `ObjectInputStream` object which is leading to stream mismatch and hence violating the internal consistency checks.That's why `StreamCorruptedException` is thrown at client side.So Instead of using `ObjectInputStream` to read the plain message sent by server you should use `BufferedReader` object that you had created above.**

So at client side your code should be modified to:

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(kkSocket.getInputStream());
String message = in.readLine();//use BufferedReader to read the plain message coming from Server.
System.out.println("Message from server: "+message);
out.println("user");
Object obj = objectInput.readObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `InputStreamReader` with byte input streams. It expects characters / strings from input streams. Try [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) instead.

Just a hint: input stream types should match both on the server side and on the client side. You cannot mix them. On the server you're using `ObjectOutputStream`, so the corresponding `ObjectInputStream` should be used on the client.