# NotSerializableException in Android

Tags: android, notserializableexception

I verified from the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html) that boolean and byte are serializable. As per the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), my class implements the serializable interface. I am not sure why I keep getting the exception. What am I missing here?
The class is like this:

```
public class msgStruct implements Serializable {
    boolean pingPong = false; 
    int msgId = 0;
    byte[] bufferMsg = new byte[100];
}
```

This is serialized before being sent via a socket to the server, like this:

```
sendMsgStruct.pingPong = false;
sendMsgStruct.msgId = msgId;
rand.nextBytes(sendMsgStruct.bufferMsg);
try {
    ObjectOutputStream serializeMobile = new ObjectOutputStream(mobileSocket.getOutputStream());
    serializeMobile.writeObject(sendMsgStruct);
    serializeMobile.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

The server deserializes like this:

```
try {
     ObjectInputStream deserializeServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
     recvMsgStruct = (msgStruct) deserializeServer.readObject();
     deserializeServer.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the exception at the lines where the object is serialized and deserialized.

Comment: Is msgStruct an inner class? Java does not support serialization of non-static inner classes. If msgStruct is an inner class, try changing the access modifier to static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is msgStruct an inner class by chance? If so, then try to make it static, or move it to its own java file.

Comment: bgse and @rhoadster91 - thanks. msgStruct was indeed an inner class and I moved it to its own java file. I no longer get the NotSerializableException. However, I am now getting - StreamCorruptedException. As per this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733449/streamcorruptedexception-when-sending-serialized-objects-via-bluetooth, I initialize the output and the inputStreams just once when the socket is created. The client sends 4 messages and on the 4th msg it throws the StreamCorruptedException. The server on the other hand, receives only the 3rd msg. Is this a timing issue?