# java serialization and deserializaion

Tags: java, serialization

I have created a simple program that serializes String input from cmd to a .ser file.. Part of the requirement is that the program must be able to append new input and be able to read the new input plus the old input.. But i get StreamCorruptedException if i read after the 2nd input..

here is my run on the CMD.. how do I solve this StreamCorruptedException and Why does it happen??. codes are given below.

```
C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java WriteFile cc.ser
Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.
hah
haha
hahaha
try
^Z

C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java WriteFile cc.ser
Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.
asd
asd
asd
asd
asd
^Z

C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java ReadFile cc.ser
1: haha
2: haha
3: hahaha 
4: hahaha
The Error is :
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:23)
```

WriteFile.java:

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class WriteFile implements java.io.Serializable
 {
public static void main(String args[])  
    {   
        try
        {
           File myFile = new File(args[0]);

           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
                                          (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
               ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream
                                          (new FileOutputStream(myFile,true));

           System.out.println("Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.");

           String str;

           while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)

            {

                    oos.writeObject(str);
            }


           br.close();
           oos.close();
        }

        catch (IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

ReadFile.java:

```
import java.io.*;
    public class ReadFile
    {       
public static void main(String args[])
    {

        try
        {
        int ctr = 0;

        File myFile = new File(args[0]);

            ObjectInputStream OIS = new ObjectInputStream 
                                               (new FileInputStream( myFile )); 
        String str;



             while ((str = (String)OIS.readObject()) != null)

            {   

               System.out.println(++ctr + ": " + str);

            }

            OIS.close();        
        }

        catch (EOFException ex)
        {
          System.out.println("\nEnd of File Reached ");
        }



        catch (ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
          System.out.println("The Error is : ");
          c.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException i)
        {
          System.out.println("The Error is : ");
          i.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending to an ObjectOutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream)

Comment: `readObject()` does not return null at end of stream. You should be catching `EOFException` for that case.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs whenever u are trying to create a new OutputStream Object for an existing input stream/trying to read even before something is written in which case ,the  control information that was read from an object stream violates internal consistency checks.

Use a single OOS and OIS for the life of the socket, and don't use any other streams on the socket.

Also u might want to implement the same using threads in the same program.

If you want to forget what you've written, use ObjectOutputStream.reset().

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occurs because u are trying to read even before it is written .

Answer (score 0):

i edited my code after reading some answer to this question [Appending to an ObjectOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream)

```
import java.io.*;



public class WriteFile
implements java.io.Serializable
{

public static void main(String args[])  
    {

        try
        {
           File myFile = new File(args[0]);

           BufferedReader br = 
                           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

           if (myFile.exists())
                {
                   AppendingObjectOutputStream AOOS = new   AppendingObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile,true));                                      
                       System.out.println("Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.");

                   String str;

                           while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)

                         {

                             AOOS.writeObject(str);
                         }


                     br.close();
                     AOOS.flush();

                }

         else
          { 
           ObjectOutputStream OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile,true));
           System.out.println("Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.");

           String str;

           while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)

            {

                    OOS.writeObject(str);
            }


           br.close();
           OOS.flush();
          }

        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

}}
```

and adding a new class from the question mentioned above

```
public class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
  super(out);
}

@Override
protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
  // do not write a header, but reset:
  // this line added after another question
  // showed a problem with the original
 reset();
}}
```

any suggestion to better improve this code? sorry just a newbie to java programming

here was my new run on the CMD

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MSI>cmd
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java WriteFile haha.ser
Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.
a
b
c
d
^Z

C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java WriteFile haha.ser
Enter text and press ^Z or ^D to end.
e
f
g
^Z

C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Codes For Java>java ReadFile haha.ser
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: e
6: f
7: g

End of File Reached
```

i did'nt change my readfile.java file... thanks for the answers =D

Answer (score -1):

A couple of questions you need to be clear before heading into your code and fix your coding issue.

1) Why do you need to use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream? If you are just read and write string, better to use BufferedWriter and BufferedReader. We only use OIS and OOS to read and write object.

2) Your question is nothing related to the Serialization and De-serialization . Please do a google search to see how to do the proper serialize and de-serialize. In your code snippet:

```
public class WriteFile implements java.io.Serializable // there is no meaning to implement the mark up interface here.
```

In short, only mark java.io.Serializable on a POJO or data object.

3) When you type ctrl-c or ctrl-z, there is a system interrupt signal triggered, the whole system will stop abruptly, that will cause the corruption of the data writing.

I spent a bit of time to write a complete **working sample** for you. Hopefully you can get sth from my sample.

ConsoleWriter

```
/**
    * Write Console String to a file
    * When you type quit or save it will write to the file in one go.
    * 
    * @author Seabook Chen
    *
*/
public class SimpleConsoleWriter {
    private static final String NEW_LINE =  System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Please specify the file name!!!");
        }

        String filepath = args[0];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your comments ....");
        System.out.println("Type quit to finish the input! Please type exact quit to quit!!!");
        System.out.println("Type save to write to the file you specified. ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(true) {
            String input = in.nextLine();

            if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(input) || "save".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for using the program!!!");
                System.out.println("Your input is stored in " + filepath);
                break;
            }

            sb.append(input);
            sb.append(NEW_LINE);

        }

        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(filepath, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(sb.toString(), 0, sb.toString().length());
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fw != null) {
                try {
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

SimpleConsoleReader

```
/**
 * Read a file and output in the console 
 * 
 * @author Seabook Chen
 *
 */
public class SimpleConsoleReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Please specify the file name!!!");
        }
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String nextLine = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(nextLine);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fr != null) {
                try {
                    fr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Your question is nothing related to the Serialization" Wrong. Your `ConsoleWriter` sample doesn't check the `readLine()` result for null and so will throw `NullPointerExceptions`. Answer is mostly irrelevant. -1

Comment: I have no idea why you down vote me? I spent 30 mins to write the program to help answer the question and no one appreciated. There might be bugs in the code. It's just a quick demo. Anyway, let it be.

Comment: I double checked my code. There is no NPE, so you never run my code and just guess. Anyway, I dont have much to say.