# Open,Close ObjectOuputStream but still want to Append the serialized objects tot the end ?

Tags: java, file-io

I am obliged to open a `ObjectOutputStream`, then write an object an finally close the stream. I do that multiple times using the following code :

```
 // try-with-statement is very practical 
 try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("G.txt") ;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);){

    oos.writeObject(v);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But what I want is to **append** the objects serialized in the "G.txt" ? how to do that please ? I can't figure that out ?

Comment: Serialized data is not text: it is binary. Don't save it in a file with a .txt extension.

Comment: Well seen, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `FileOutputStream` into append mode for the second and subsequent writes, but you must also use an `AppendingObjectOutputStream` for the second and subsequent writes. You will find this class all over the Internet. It overrides `writeStreamHeader()` to do nothing. Otherwise you will get a [`StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code AC`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395269/207421) on reading, when you get to the join.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)` constructor.

Comment: No it isn't. That will suffice to append the data, but it will throw a [`StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code AC`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2395269/207421) on reading, when you get to the join.

Comment: it is not adviced to OpenClose multiple times the OOS or OIS ?

Comment: @OSryx It doesn't work. Follow the link and see why. It is possible to overcome this issue but it's best not to provoke it in the first place.

Comment: If you want to append to the file, You can subclass ObjectOutputStream and override `writeStreamHeader` method  to do a `reset()`. Then select the ObjectOutputStream bansed on use cases(when appending, use the subclasses OOS ans when not appending use the OOS).