# How to avoid java.io.StreamCorruptedException?

Tags: java

I have a method that writes data from a list to a file, a method that reads data from a file into a list and a method that writes data from a list in a file to the specified number of times. I'm trying to extract data from a file after I use the first method `writeFile ()` everything works fine. I read the data from the file into the list by `readFile ()` method. After that I use my method which writes to the file the number of times I need, everything is fine, it writes `multyWrite ()`. But after that I can not read the data from the file in the `readFile ()` method since I get `

Exception stack trace:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC     
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)   
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)      
at ProductService.readFile(ProductService.java:47)  
at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I know that I should use `objectOutputStream.reset ()`, but where would it be better to use it?

```
private String fileName;
    private ProductInterface<FlyingMachine> productService = new ProductInterfaceImpl();
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;


    public ProductService(String fileName) throws IOException {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        this.objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    }

public void writeFile() throws IOException {
        try {
            for (FlyingMachine f : productService.getProductContainer()) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(f);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (objectOutputStream != null) {
                objectOutputStream.flush();
                objectOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }`

public void readFile() throws IOException {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            while (fileInputStream.available() > 0) {
                FlyingMachine flyingMachine = (FlyingMachine) objectInputStream.readObject();
                productService.getProductContainer().add(flyingMachine);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | EOFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
                objectInputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

public void multyWrite(int number) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                for (FlyingMachine f : productService.getProductContainer()) {
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(f);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (objectOutputStream != null) {
                    objectOutputStream.flush();
                    objectOutputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without the complete stacktrace it's hard to figure out. But may be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac helps you.

Comment: Don't use `available()` like that. It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: If I do not use available (), I get EOFException

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `ObjectOutputStream` in the constructor. In `writeFile` you use that `OOS` instance and close it. But in `multyWrite` you don't use it and instead create new instances.

Now when you call `multyWrite` without having called `writeFile` first, that first `OOS` will still be open, but the `OOS` you create in `multyWrite` doesn't know that - thus causing your file to have two `OOS` headers after another.

And then when you try to read such a file, the `ObjectInputStream` will find the first header (all is fine) and then unexpectedly find the second header, while it expected a type code. That header starts with `0xAC`, hence throwing the exception message *"invalid type code: AC"*.

To fix this, either have `multyWrite` use the `OOS` constructed in your constructor, the same way `writeFile` does, or make sure that that `OOS` is closed before you create a new one.

It's generally not a good idea to open a stream (of any kind) in a constructor and then rely on external code calling a specific method to close it. Better create streams when you need them and close them directly.