Java Server Client ObjectInputStream error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
I want to save to a .dat file and need to create ObjectInputStream newOis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));. However I already had a ois created which lead to error  java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC. How can I fix this problem?
I tried to change the current ois to a new object and create a new ois, however neither of them is working.
Client
public class ChatClient implements Runnable{
private int serverPort = 777;
private User user;
private boolean userAdded = false;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private ArrayList<User> connectedUsers;

public ChatClient() throws IOException {
    new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", serverPort);
        System.out.println("Connected to chatServer");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while (true) {
            try {
                if(!userAdded){
                    addUserToServer();
                    //Thread that handle incoming message
                    new Thread(() -> {
                        try {
                            while (true) {
                                Object receivedObject = ois.readObject();
                                if (receivedObject instanceof Message) {
                                    Message serverMessage = (Message) receivedObject;
                                    System.out.println(serverMessage.getSender().getUsername() + ": " + serverMessage.getText());
                                } else if (receivedObject instanceof ArrayList) {
                                    connectedUsers = (ArrayList<User>) receivedObject;
                                    printConnectedUser(connectedUsers);
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Type in userChoice");
                    Scanner menuScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int userMenuChoice;
                    userMenuChoice = menuScanner.nextInt();

                    if(userMenuChoice == 1){
                        /*oos.reset();
                        oos.writeInt(userMenuChoice);
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Write message");
                        String username;
                        username = scanner.nextLine();
                        Message message = new Message(username, null, user, null, false);
                        oos.writeObject(message);*/

                        //Receive connectedUser list
                        oos.reset();
                        oos.writeInt(userMenuChoice);
                        oos.flush();
                        String userToSend;
                        ArrayList<String> receiver = new ArrayList<>();
                        boolean userIsOnline = false;

                        while(true){
                            System.out.println("Your contact list, Write name you want to send message to");
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                            userToSend = scanner.nextLine();

                            receiver.add(userToSend);

                            System.out.println("Do you want to write to more ?");
                            int writeToMore = scanner.nextInt();

                            if(writeToMore == 1){
                            }
                            else{
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        sendMessageToUser(userIsOnline, receiver);

                    }
                    else if(userMenuChoice == 2){
                        oos.reset();
                        oos.writeInt(userMenuChoice);
                        oos.flush();
                        System.out.println("Add user to contact list, type user you want to add!");
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String userToAdd;
                        userToAdd = scanner.nextLine();

                        //Add user to contact
                        for(int i = 0; i < connectedUsers.size(); i++){
                            if(Objects.equals(userToAdd, connectedUsers.get(i).getUsername())){
                                user.addContact(connectedUsers.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(userMenuChoice == 3){
                        //Write contactList
                        System.out.println("Your contact list");
                        for(int i = 0; i < user.getContactList().size(); i++){
                            System.out.println(user.getContactList().get(i).getUsername());
                        }
                    }
                    //oos.flush();
                }
                //socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public void addUserToServer() throws IOException {
    //Send user to server
    System.out.println("Username: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username = scanner.next();
    user = new User(username, null, new ArrayList<>());
    oos.writeObject(user);
    //oos.flush();
    userAdded = true;
}

public void printConnectedUser(ArrayList<User> connectedUser){
    for(int i = 0; i < connectedUser.size(); i++){
        if(!Objects.equals(connectedUser.get(i).getUsername(), user.getUsername())){
            System.out.println(connectedUser.get(i).getUsername());
        }
    }
}

public void sendMessageToUser(boolean sendAble, ArrayList<String> receiver) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write message");
    String username;
    username = scanner.nextLine();
    //Add list of receiver
    Message message = new Message(username, null, user, receiver, sendAble);
    oos.writeObject(message);
}

}
Server (ClientHandler)
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private Message userMessage;
private ChatServer chatServer;
private User user;
private boolean userAdded = false;
private ArrayList<User> userListFile;
public ClientHandler(Socket socket, ChatServer chatServer) throws IOException {
    this.chatServer = chatServer;
    this.socket = socket;
    // Create input and output streams for communication
    this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    userListFile = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        setUser();
        //sleep(5000);
        saveUserToFile("src/files/user.dat");
        checkUnsentMessages();

        while(true){
            try{
                int userChoice = ois.readInt();
                System.out.println("Userchoice " + userChoice);

                if(userChoice == 1){
                    //Send connectedUser except for the current user to the client
                    sendConnectedUserToClient();

                    userMessage = (Message) ois.readObject();

                    //Check the onlineUserList
                    //Send the online user to them and offline to unsent messages


                    if(userMessage != null){
                        ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandlers = chatServer.getConnectedUser();
                        ArrayList<String> receiver = userMessage.getReceiver();

                        for(int i = 0; i < userMessage.getReceiver().size(); i++){
                            boolean sentToOnlineUser = false;
                            for(int k = 0; k < chatServer.getConnectedUser().size(); k++){
                                if(Objects.equals(clientHandlers.get(k).getUser().getUsername(), receiver.get(i))) {
                                    clientHandlers.get(k).getOos().writeObject(userMessage);
                                    clientHandlers.get(k).getOos().flush();
                                    sentToOnlineUser = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!sentToOnlineUser){
                                Message unsentMessage = new Message(userMessage.getText(), null, userMessage.getSender(), new ArrayList<>(), true);
                                unsentMessage.addReceiver(receiver.get(i));
                                chatServer.addUnsentMessage(unsentMessage);
                            }
                        }
                        /*
                        //Get time server receive
                        userMessage.setTimeServerReceive();
                        LocalDateTime serverReceiveDate = userMessage.getNow();
                        int serverReceiveMillis = userMessage.getMillis();
                        System.out.println( "Receiver: " + userMessage.getReceiver() + serverReceiveDate + " " + serverReceiveMillis + " " + userMessage.getSender().getUsername() + ": " + userMessage.getText());
                        sendMessageToUser(userMessage);*/
                    }
                }
                else if (userChoice == 2) {
                    sendConnectedUserToClient();
                }
                else if (userChoice == 3) {

                }

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                System.out.println(user.getUsername() + " has disconnect.");
                break;
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
        chatServer.removeUser(this);
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void setUser() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    user = (User) ois.readObject();
    userAdded = true;
    if(user.getUsername() != null){
        chatServer.addUser(this);
        chatServer.showConnectedUser();
    }
}

public Message getMessage(){
    return userMessage;
}

public void sendMessageToAll(Message message) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandlers = chatServer.getConnectedUser();
    if(message != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < clientHandlers.size(); i++){
            if(clientHandlers.get(i) != this){
                oos.writeObject(message);
                oos.flush();
            }
        }
        //Set time server send
    }
}

public void sendMessageToUser(Message message) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandlers = chatServer.getConnectedUser();
    ArrayList<String> receiver = message.getReceiver();

    for(int i = 0; i < receiver.size(); i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < clientHandlers.size(); k++){
            if(Objects.equals(clientHandlers.get(k).getUser().getUsername(), receiver.get(i))){
                clientHandlers.get(k).getOos().writeObject(message);
                clientHandlers.get(k).getOos().flush();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
public User getUser(){
    return user;
}

public void sendConnectedUserToClient() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<ClientHandler> connectedUser = chatServer.getConnectedUser();
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < connectedUser.size(); i++){
        userArrayList.add(connectedUser.get(i).getUser());
        System.out.println(userArrayList.get(i).getUsername());
    }
    oos.reset();
    oos.writeObject(userArrayList);
    oos.flush();
}

public ObjectOutputStream getOos(){
    return oos;
}


public void checkUnsentMessages() throws IOException {
    //Check for unsent messages loop
    //If the onlineUserList contain the user getMessage and remove the user from Message onlineUserList
    ArrayList<Message> unsentMessages = chatServer.getUnsentMessages();

    for(int i = 0; i < unsentMessages.size(); i++){
        if(Objects.equals(user.getUsername(), unsentMessages.get(i).getReceiver().get(0))){
            oos.writeObject(unsentMessages.get(i));
            oos.flush();
            chatServer.removeUnsentMessage(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void saveUserToFile(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    readUserFromFile(filename);
    //Check if the username exist, if yes client login as the user else add the client to user.dat
    boolean userAssigned = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < userListFile.size(); i++){
        if (Objects.equals(user.getUsername(), userListFile.get(i).getUsername())){
            //Login as that user
            user = userListFile.get(i);
            userAssigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!userAssigned){
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename, true))) {
            oos.writeObject(user);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    readUserFromFile(filename);
}

public void readUserFromFile(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    userListFile.clear();

    File file = new File(filename);

    if (file.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("File is empty.");
        return;
    }

    //this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    oos.reset();
    ObjectInputStream newOis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

    for(int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++){
        User obj = (User) newOis.readObject();
        if (obj != null) {
            userListFile.add(obj);
        }
    }

    /*try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                User obj = (User) newOis.readObject();
                if (obj != null) {
                    userListFile.add(obj);
                }
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                break; // Exit the loop when end of file is reached
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Handle ClassNotFoundException if needed
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    } finally {

    }*/


}

}

Your question is unclear, but I suspect that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393179.  The bottom line is that you cannot concatenate object output streams ...

If you disagree that it is a duplicate, please provide a minimal reproducible example, and detailed instructions that will allow us to reproduce your problem.

@StephenC  I forgot to add my code. The problem is on the last method from ClientHandler.

Yup.  Your code confirms my diagnosis.  This line will append the serialized object to an existing file: new FileOutputStream(filename, true).  That will give you a file that cannot be read fully using ObjectInputStream.
